# How to convert LPCTSTR to C# string using SWIG

Tags: c#, mfc, swig

I have to rebuild software that was written in C++/MFC & Unicode. There are two assemblies, one Server and one Client. The Client has to be rebuilt in C#+WPF.
Originally there was a .h file included by both assemblies, to share some global values. I want to use these values in the new C# assembly, too.

My first approach is to use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/). So I created a test-Project (that Outputs a DLL) that contains the .h file and let do SWIG its Magic.
This results in a C++ Wrapper for the C++ Project and some .cs files.
Then I created a C# WPF application, included the DLL and the generated cs files from swig.

So far so good.

The .h file contains basically int variables, classes that contain an enum each and some LPCTSTR strings (that are wchar_t * since I use Unicode).

```
const LPCTSTR ProductName = _T("XYZ");
const int MAX_MESS_ITEMS = 200;
class SPS
{
public:
    enum SPS
    {
        SPS1 = 1,
        SPS2 = 2,
        SPS3 = 3,
    };
};
```

Using the int and enums is no Problem, but swig isn't able to convert the LPCTSTR to C# string (without doing some customizing). Swig generates a `SWIGTYPE_p_LPCTSTR` type which does not allow me to get the original Content of the string as defined in the .h file.

As a next Approach I walked through the SWIG Documentation (I use version 3.0.12) and found out about typedef and typemaps.
I tried to include the windows.i and that gave me the first letter of the string assigned to a LPCTSTR variable.
Next I tried to figure out how to use a typemap for this, but I can't get this to work. For me it is pretty difficult to understand how to create a typemap (I have some Problems understanding what is done there and how the Syntax works). Also the lib (that I downloaded with the swigwin.zip) that contains some typemaps for std::string etc. does not help me.
Also Research on stackoverflow and MSDN did not take me closer to a solution.

Are there any good instructions or examples on how to crate a typemap for converting strings (especialy LPCTSTR) ?
What other easy-to-use tools can make the Job? Should I stop using SWIG and use `_declspec(dllexport)` stuff (with what I don't have any experience)?

I'm not in the Need to convert functions or highly-desgined classes. Just the strings, int, and enums.
Since the two assemblies are communicating over a namedpipe, I concerned to send some data over the pipe when starting the applications, but there are some Information from the global variables needed before the pipe starts doing its work.

Any help concerning this is appreciated :)

Comment: Why don't you use a separate assembly in C++/CLI?

Comment: For what exactly?

In order to use the classes generated by SWIG, I extracted the .h file into a separate C++-DLL that is used by my main assemblies.

Comment: You should provide your interface file so we could see what you've already done and help you and maybe correct your mistake(s).

Comment: This is the content of my globdef.i file

`%module GlobDef 
%{
    #include "globdef.h"
%}

//%include "windows.i"
%include "globdef.h"`